# Find Min value in row from Dynamic Datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datatable, rows, dynamic-columns

So I have 2 datatables, The 1st datatable is a traditional datatable which gets its data from certain sql statements.

Datatable 1:

```
 | user_point |  | lat       |  | lng        |  | radius      |
 --------------------------------------------------------------
 | userpoint0 |  | 43.702943 |  | -79.37478  |  | 3.10685596  | 
 | userpoint1 |  | 43.672655 |  | -79.479837 |  | 4.970969536 |
```

However, the certain columns are dynamically generated in Datatable 2 based on the number of userpoints in Datatable 1.

```
 | id    |    | lat              | | lng               |  | DistanceFromUserpoint0 | | DistanceFromUserpoint1 | 
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | 23184 |    | 43.6495246887207 | | -79.4244003295898 |  | 4.4464409231533  |       | 3.19880848195014 | 
 | 37957 |    | 43.6372413635254 | | -79.4151458740234 |  | 4.96760996486758 |       | 4.05524888969018 | 
 | 37965 |    | 43.636589050293  | | -79.4169921875    |  | 5.04670564187353 |       | 4.00990129127938 | 
 | 60467 |    | 43.735538482666  | | -79.4437942504883 |  | 4.11692339031897 |       | 4.70303114025665 | 
 | 60475 |    | 43.735538482666  | | -79.4437942504883 |  | 4.11692339031897 |       | 4.70303114025665 | 
 | 65615 |    | 43.7292861938477 | | -79.4317932128906 |  | 3.37923630122185 |       | 4.59015403452972 | 
 | 65623 |    | 43.7292861938477 | | -79.4317932128906 |  | 3.37923630122185 |       | 4.59015403452972 | 
 | 3196486 |  | 43.6624603271484 | | -79.4242172241211 |  | 3.7316961595166  |       | 2.86768157143755 | 
 | 3196494 |  | 43.6624603271484 | | -79.4242172241211 |  | 3.7316961595166  |       | 2.86768157143755 | 
 | 5756393 |  | 43.719165802002  | | -79.4295654296875 |  | 2.95683309139676 |       | 4.07847187106957 | 
 | 5756922 |  | 43.719165802002  | | -79.4295654296875 |  | 2.95683309139676 |       | 4.07847187106957 | 
 | 5756956 |  | 43.719165802002  | | -79.4295654296875 |  | 2.95683309139676 |       | 4.07847187106957 | 
 | 5756991 |  | 43.719165802002  | | -79.4295654296875 |  | 2.95683309139676 |       | 4.07847187106957 | 
 | 5757096 |  | 43.719165802002  | | -79.4295654296875 |  | 2.95683309139676 |       | 4.07847187106957 |
 | 5757134 |  | 43.719165802002  | | -79.4295654296875 |  | 2.95683309139676 |       | 4.07847187106957 |
```

Now I will add a new column at the end of datatable 2 called the `Closest_userpoint` which will store the value of the distance which is the closest userpoint for that row.

So now my question is how to I find the the smallest/min value for that row, which has columns that are dynamically generated(which means there can be any number of userpoints from none to 100). I am looking for a simplest and most efficient answer, Thank you

**EDIT:**

Here is my code for how the dynamic columns are created, However I am stuck on figuring out the logic to fill the closestUserpoint Column with min value for that row based on the distancefromuserpoints

**EDIT 2:**

**BONUS QUESTION:**

Finally I want to determine if that closest Point/Min value falls within the raidus for that userpoint which it is closest.

Comment: There are a few ways to do that. Would you show us what you have tried/thought of so far?

Comment: I posted my code, for how i am Dynamically calculating the distancefromuserpoints and creating the columns I am stuck on figuring out the logic to fill the closetUserpoint Column with the min value.

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but SQL2008 will do this kind of 'Which is the closest point to X' for you using some new geography features

Comment: I would like everything do to be done in C# code itself, since I am not saving my distance values in sql at all, since there columns are dynamically generated which wouldnt be very efficient if I am saving them in sql like that

Comment: @AdrianCarneiro if I can do this more efficiently with sql itself, without the use of c# please suggest how to write my query to get the closestpoints, table1(userpoint, lat, lng, radius)  and table2(id, lat, lng)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be easier if you try finding the minimum values after populating the values

use System.Linq; for the Min() method

```
if (userpoints.Rows.Count > 1)
{
foreach (DataRow dr in selectedPanels.Rows)
{
List<string> alluserpoints = new List<string>();             
for (int i = 0; i < userpoints.Rows.Count; i++)
{
if (Convert.ToDouble(userpoints.Rows[i].radius) > Convert.ToDouble(dr["DistanceFromUserpoint" + i]))
{
    alluserpoints.Add(dr["DistanceFromUserpoint" + i]+"+userpoint"+i);
}
}
if(alluserpoints.Count>0)
dr["Closest_UserPoint"] = alluserpoints.Min();  
else
dr["Closest_UserPoint"] ="none";                        
}
}
else
{
foreach(DataRow dr in selectedPanels.Rows)
{
if(Convert.ToDouble(userpoints.Rows[0].radius>Convert.ToDouble(dr["DistanceFromUserpoint0"])
{
dr["Closest_UserPoint"]=dr["DistanceFromUserpoint0"]+"+userpoint0";
}
else
{
dr["Closest_UserPoint"]="none";
}
}
}
```

Comment: i would prefer not to use Linq, because I am not using it anywhere else in my code. this would work, but can you suggest a solution without using linq please.

Comment: also, I still need to find out. if that closest point/distance falls within the radius of that userpoint.

Comment: you can then sort the alluserpoints list using Sort() method and assign alluserpoints[0] to the closest userpoint. Its not the most efficient solution but if you are really particular on doing this in C# code then use it.

Comment: @programmer_41 Oh then i guess you have to use LINQ. Doing that without LINQ will be too complex.

Comment: @programmer_41 i have edited my answer so that only distances that are within the radius will be considered and added to the list.

Comment: your solution doesnt work, it is not giving me the correct closest point, please see the below table

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37354/discussion-between-programmer-41-and-nithin-nayagam)

Comment: I editing my quesiton with the updated table to your solution it doesnt give the correct value for that row, i think the list is storing the values for the column not the row